# Create dynamic library from cpp files and static library with clang

Tags: macos, shared-libraries, clang, static-libraries

I have following problem:

I have static lib called `libAlgatorc.a` and three cpp files calle `SortingAbsAlgorithm.cpp`, `SortingTestCase.cpp` and `SortingTestSetIterator.cpp`.

Now, I want to create dynamic library that will contain symbols from cpp files and from static lib. I can do this in Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 x64, g++ version 4.8.1) like this:

```
g++ -fPIC SortingAbsAlgorithm.cpp SortingTestCase.cpp SortingTestSetIterator.cpp -shared -o libProject.so -Wl,--whole-archive -lAlgatorc -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

But I can't do this on OS X. clang doesn't have -Wl,--whole-archive option.

I have folowing clang version:

```
$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.53.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Apple's [Dynamic Library Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/CreatingDynamicLibraries.html), probably something like:

```
clang -dynamiclib \
    SortingAbsAlgorithm.cpp SortingTestCase.cpp SortingTestSetIterator.cpp \
    -stdlib=libc++ -current_version 1.0 -compatibility_version 1.0 \
    -fvisibility=hidden -L. -lAlgatorc -o libProject.dylib
```

Given I've specified `-stdlib=libc++` you probably want `-mmacosx-version-min=10.7` as well.

So really it's just `-dynamiclib` that's important.